# I can't import MaterialViewPager library into android project

Tags: android

I new Dev and I have a android project. I try add MaterialViewPager into my project but when I try rebuild it, I get some error look like this img.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1WNU.png)

[My gradle file :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvlM3.png)

Answer (score 0):

You must include this on your gradle file:

```
compile ('com.github.florent37:materialviewpager:1.2.0@aar'){
    transitive = true
}
```